# in Android Studio, how can I change an app project to a library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I'm sure this is simple, but since I just started using Android Studio today, I can't find it.  I have also googled for the past hour and found no posts that specify:

how to change an existing application project to a library.

Everything I found was about how to create a new library project. Not how to convert one.

A sub-question, is how can I see if a project is configured as an application or a library?  I would hope that the answer to both of these questions is the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open your `build.gradle` of your app (inside your app directory) and modify :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

If you have an `applicationId` in your `build.gradle` remove it :

```
defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.your.application.id"
}
```

then clean your project and rebuild or just sync your gradle from Android Studio

If you have added some extra gradle properties like `applicationVariants.all` you must replace with `libraryVariants.all` and vice-versa if you convert a library to application

If you want to add a new step to your reconversion you can change the module name "app" created by default by Android-Studio with a name more adapted to a library module. You can rename the directory app with `<your_module_name>`. open `settings.gradle` file (at the root of your project) and replace app with `<your_module_name>`. Then Go to Menu Build > Make module `<your_module_name>` and there you are, your module is renamed.

Comment: excellent answer.  Thank you.  Btw, I also just found similar content here - https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/2c46cf33e3814e685b47 . Thanks again.

Comment: also move _apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'_ to You application module

Answer (score 0):

**Changing to Library**

1. Goto android project, where you need to change as Library module.
2. In build.gradle(:app) file,

- change this line to

  ```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    }
  ```

  to

  ```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    }
  ```

3. Delete the line for the **applicationId** in same build.gradle(:app) file

   ```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.example" //remove this line
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
   ```
4. Now Sync Project with Gradle Files.